# Comparison of sets $A = \{e^{i\phi} + e^{i\theta} | \phi,\theta \in \Bbb R \}$ and $B = \{1- e^{i\theta} | \theta \in \Bbb R \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am at the first year of undergrad CS studies, and we have this question in algebra workbook. In this task I am supposed to find the connection between these sets, but I am not even sure how to interpret them geometrically in 2-dimensional coordinate plane (for complex numbers). Is it even possible to be done?

I know for sure that elements of $A = \{e^{i\phi} + e^{i\theta} | \phi,\theta \in  \Bbb R \}$ can be derived to be viewed as:

$$2\cos{{\phi - \theta} \over 2}e^{i({\phi + \theta}) \over 2}$$

And elements of $B = \{1-  e^{i\theta} | \theta \in  \Bbb R \}$ as:
$$2\sin{{\theta} \over 2}e^{i({\theta - \pi}) \over 2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint first is a circle centred at $cos\phi+isin\phi$ and $e^{i\theta}$ represents standard circle at $(0,0)$  and 1 can be represented as $e^{i\pi}$ . Now we know its a circle centred at . Now look at your second expansion it should be $e^{\frac{\theta}{2}+\pi}$ as $i^2=-1$ so $i.i=\pi/2+\pi/2$ according to De moivre's theorem

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\{e^{i\theta}\}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}$ is the unit circle centered at the origin.

$\{(a+bi)+e^{i\theta}\}_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}$ is the unit circle centered at $a+bi$.